# How to send back end request in Postman in a loop

Tags: postman

I am very new in using Postman. So please forgive me if this question is very naive to be asked in here.

I have a back end request that I want to repeat 1000 times. I have copied cURL the request from fire fox debugger tool / network tab and imported it in to postman.

Now instead of pushing send 1000 time I want to right an script to do it in post man. Do I put that script in pre-request script or test tab? after I wrote my script how do I run it?

Some thing like following : where get is the name of the request that I have saved.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  postman.setNextRequest("get");  
}
```

Comment: You could just create a single request and use the runner to run it X number of times - https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/starting_a_collection_run/#customizing-requests-in-collection-runner

Comment: @DannyDainton thank you that worked just fine - way easier than I thought